# No confirmation question on second comment flag

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, flags

Not a big deal, but I just flagged two comments on the same thread, but I only got the "Really flag?" question on the first flag; the second one went right through.

If that's of importance: I was a little too quick, so the first time I tried to flag the second comment, I got the red 5-second box.

Comment: @Jarrod, @balpha: `[status-completed]`?

Comment: @Jon yes, I can't repo - must have been fixed a long time ago :)

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak for the devs (re the motivation), but I'm not sure I'd consider that a bug... the chances are that if you've read (and acknowledged) the message once on that page, then you probably know what you're doing - perhaps flagging a comment war (although a moderator flag would be useful too if it is out of hand).

Comment: True, might even be by design. Just felt odd.

Answer (score 1):

Although I agree with Marc that it is possible that it only shows up once since it will assume you know what you are doing the second time around, that doesn't really take into account situations where you may misclick. There have been several times that I attempted to upvote, but I just flat out missed and accidentally flagged (and as a mod once accidentally deleted the comment).

Comment: That's the problem with hooves!

Comment: I know. It's all so frustrating!