# My votes went boom!

Tags: bug, status-norepro, election

Today morning (eight hours ago), I cast my votes in the primary.

I checked back later to see how well the election was going, and I see that my votes for minitech, Lix, slugster, Neal, TheifMaster, and Lucifer have been reversed (No, I'm not telling you what they were initially). Also, I'm quite sure I voted for Brad and that vote had disappeared too.

I fixed the votes and opened a copy of the page in a new tab... and my votes for animuson, Moshe, slugster, Lucifer, Neal, and TheifMaster were reversed.

A vote for jcolebrand had appeared out of nowhere.

My vote for Kevin had disappeared.

I fixed it again.

I opened *another* tab, and a whole new bunch of votes were reversed/removed/added.

Is this SE's implementation of a George Bush factor?

Comment: This sounds very strange

Comment: @Lucifer: Can you check the election page and see if your votes have stayed where you told them to?

Comment: I'm seeing your votes immediately followed be un-votes in the log. I'll investigate further. Your latest bunch of votes seem to be fine, though; can you confirm that?

Comment: you *are* going to vote for these candidates, and you *are* going to like it. Still, odd.

Comment: @TimManishEarth, yes, here it is showing everything fine, i voted in the morning and still it is showing properly ( i user chrome )

Comment: @balpha: Nope. TheifMaster got reversed again. Twice. I have fixed the vote, lets see what a refresh gives.

Comment: @TimManishEarth are you voting too fast ?

Comment: Hmm, now the votes are showing properly. I'll wait a while and see if anything changes.

Comment: @Lucifer: Nope. 8 hours, right? _Now_ I am voting fast, when I'm trying to fix this.

Comment: I haven't seen any such weirdness; my votes are still where I left them last night.

Comment: @TimManishEarth  i mean you vote on one user and immediateness

Comment: @TimManishEarth i mean you vote on one user and, just in next 2-3 second you caste vote on another user, like that (fast) ?

Comment: @Lucifer: Hmm, in the morning I was voting rapidly at times. Don't think that that's an issue though--if the vote does not execute, there is a popup showing what happened.

Comment: Works for me (tm). You sure you have no scripts/addons/extensions messing with the page (like sorting)?

Comment: @GardenGnobobby: Nope. I switched browsers to a Chrome beta free of userscripts, problem persisted (though it only reversed TheifMaster).

Comment: <phew> Happy to report my votes are still intact. Maybe you're not voting **hard enough**.

Comment: Thanks for your vote! ^_^

Comment: @Lix: I never said I _upvoted_ you... :P (j/k, I did upvote you.) When I mean "reversal", I mean that those with an upvote were downvoted and those with a downvote were upvoted.

Comment: Some good news: Your votes were always counted. For some yet-to-be-found reason, they apparently weren't *displayed* to you, but they were correctly recorded and counted.

Comment: Lawyers are alredy ganging up to contest the results...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Facts:

1. All your votes were correctly counted, so democracy has not been harmed, despite your (hopefully tongue-in-cheek) last sentence.
2. I'm seeing some weird repeated request counts from you (contrary to my comment on your question, they were un-votes, followed by votes, not the other way around).
3. I'm seeing these strange request duplications not only for the vote requests, but for all kinds of other requests as well.
4. Curious what that might be about, I took a look at the user agent strings in your requests, seeing Chrome 20 and 21. Those are the current beta and the current dev release. I think you've been around on Meta enough to know that we don't support those, and for good reasons.

Conclusion:

I just wasted almost two hours on a browser bug occuring in an unsupported browser. Thanks.

Comment: Hmm, it didn't occur to me that it could be a problem on my side. Sorry :\

Comment: I agree wasted time sucks, but hey, this comes across a bit more pissy than is fair IMO. Consider how much time community bug feedback has *saved* you. Anyway, before filing a bug report, check your browser versions, people. (And of course, whether you are actually logged in before complaining you can't vote on your iPad. *ahem* :)

Comment: @Pekka I immensly value and appreciate the community bug feedback, [publicly](http://balpha.de/2011/06/a-shout-out-to-the-people-of-meta/). After all, I used to be one of the people posting [tiny bug reports](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16028) as well. That's why I go through lengths to try to explain [what went wrong](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/117738) or [why an issue can't be fixed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/99637). But when there's a bug report about primary votes not being counted (which is a very serious issue) -- even coming with a side dish of accusation --, ...

Comment: @Pekka ... and it turns out it all just happened because the OP made the deliberate decision to install a browser that is (by design!) extremely buggy, I think I have a right to be annoyed. That said, it's not like I'm holding a grudge now. ManishEarth is a helpful Meta user, and now he's also helping out as a pro-tem mod on chemistry, and that's great. This was just an unfortunate episode; matter closed; done.

Comment: As the OP also wrote *"A vote for jcolebrand had appeared out of nowhere"*, this might be related to some problems at least two people [reported for Safari](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175388/voting-counted-on-wrong-answer). Just wondering: would it be hard to browse the log files for the examples those two have given? (My bet would be that the  `return jClicked.closest('div.vote').find("input").val()` somehow fails after some Ajax interaction has occurred, which is scary too... But maybe Safari is firing multiple requests as well?)